# writing device drivers for OpenIndiana

Tags: solaris, device-driver, opensolaris, openindiana

Given that OpenIndiana is a fork of OpenSolaris, is it fair to say that writing device drivers for OpenIndiana should not be different from writing it on OpenSolaris?

I'm also looking for some references, or a "linux device drivers"-alike manual for  OpenIndiana. Are there any? (I could not find so far).

What I found on oracle.com:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/write-dev-driver-jsp-140901.html
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4854/

Would this be a good starting point for writing drivers on OpenIndiana?
Thanks.

Comment: The OpenIndiana is based on Illumos and while linked docs are also great, You can also start from http://illumos.org/books/wdd/ and Illumos wiki will give You other information needed. Also http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5789/817-5789.pdf will surely help.